# for loop counting issue in php

Tags: php

I have two for loop which are fetching questions from database.Questions  are associated
with parameter. There are 3 parameters having different number of questions.
What I am doing is-

```
for($j=0; $j<count(parameter); $j++) {
    echo parameter[$j]['name'];
    for($m=0; $m<count($question); $m++) {
        echo $m.'. '$question['description'];
    }
}
```

Its output is:

Location

1. Correct Address and Contact Details of ASC, in Company Systems, Website & SMS tool and matching.
2. Contactability on Landline & Mobile No of ASC

Facilities

1. Ventilation, Lighting, Power Backup & Airconditioning of the ASC
2. Infotainment System
3. Drinking Water & New Paper

AVM

1. Look & Feel, Color Code of ASC, All Parameters
2. Glow Sign Board
3. Uniforms
4. Notice board in waiting area as per latest guidelines

Location ,Facilities,AVM are parameters having 2-3 questions which are listing as 1,2 again 1,2,3
then 1,2,3,4
But I want 1,2,3,4 to 9 counting

Comment: Please print_r and show the array you get, and the array you are expecting.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. You want the counting till 9 ? please explain little bit.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code

```
$count = 1;
for($j=0;$j<count(parameter);$j++){
echo parameter[$j]['name'];
    for($m=0;$m<count($question);$m++){
    echo $count.'. '$question['description'];
    $count += 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try foreach loop

```
   foreach($parameter as $value) {
        print_r($value['name']);
        $m = 0;
        foreach($question as $description) {
            print_r($m . ". " . $description);
            $m++;
        }
    }
```